# GWT: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': 2 arguments required, but only 1 present

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, gwt-compiler

I have a GWT project so my javascript codes are generated by GWT Compiler.
After last chrome update, Javascript codes started to throw exception as "Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': 2 arguments required, but only 1 present." 
Because javascript codes have some line like:

```
b.element.dom.insertBefore(e)
```

The problem disappears if I change above code as:

```
b.element.dom.insertBefore(e, null)
```

Do GWT have to publish a new update to resolve this problem?
Or Is it possible to edit or override GWT compiler to resolve generated buggy code?

Thanks all.

Comment: Source of the problem is same, in javascript it is easy to solve. just send second parameter as null but in GWT what can we do for generators to solve problem

Comment: This problem happened to me on Adobe's edge.6.0.0.min.js running on Android Marshmallow on a Nexus 5. Adding the second parameter as null fixed my problem as well. Thks!